# Trouble understanding `self` escapes the method body here

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm very new to Rust.  I've been through the various books etc but I'm consistently having issues with code like the following.

This is a simple repro that follows the function prototype of a package I'm using

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct DoSomething {
    x: i32,
}

fn some_func(loader: impl FnOnce() + 'static) {}

impl DoSomething {
    async fn do_something(&mut self) {
        some_func(|| {
            self.x = 100;
        });
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error in the call to `some_func`

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of method
  --> src\main.rs:44:9
   |
43 |       async fn do_something(&mut self) {
   |                             ---------
   |                             |
   |                             `self` is a reference that is only valid in the method body
   |                             let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
44 | /         some_func(|| {
45 | |             self.x = 100;
46 | |         });
   | |          ^
   | |          |
   | |__________`self` escapes the method body here
   |            argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

Now I get that because the closure captures the reference of self and combined with 'static on some_func, the borrow checker can't be sure that self will be valid when the closure is eventually executed.  Is that correct?

Now the million dollar question.  Whats the right way to do something like this?

For completeness, the package I'm using is called callback-future which allows me to turn a callback into a future.  The full code I want to get working is:

```
    async fn some_async(&mut self) -> Result<String, i32> {
        CallbackFuture::new(|complete| {
            self.cb = Some(complete);
        })
        .await
    }
```

The idea is to store the complete Fn passed into the closure so I can execute when some later async workflows have completed.

Comment: The best solution really depends on the particular situation. The easiest solution is just to take `this: Arc<Mutex<Self>>` instead of `&mut self`.

Comment: idk exactly what you are doing, but maybe look into creating a normal async function, calling it, and storing the returned future for execution later. (async functions are sugar for returning futures, futures don't run until they're awaited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the library requires a `FnOnce` bound by `'static`, you must ensure that all references passed into the closure are also at least `'static`. This is the easiest solution:

```rust
impl DoSomething {
    async do_something(&'static mut self) {
        some_func(|| self.x = 100);
    }
}
```

I recommend looking into a different crate, usually you have to leak memory to obtain a static reference.

Comment: You usually don't want to give a struct a static lifetime, and if you did you'd likely initiate it at program start with something like once-cell or lazy static.

Comment: @JaredSmith yup, ideally `some_func` would be: `fn some_func<'a>(loader: impl FnOnce() + 'a)` so that a non-static reference would work

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up not using that crate and rethinking it all and making use of a future that I could resolve when I was ready.